# Pipping commands into bash result in "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I'm running a command against my Cloud Foundry instance to return the health status of my applications. To make it easy I'm trying to build the health check command for each application like this:

```
cf apps | tail -n +5 | awk 'NF{print "\"curl -s http://" $6 "/cloudfoundryapplication/health | jq \\\".status\\\" && echo \\\"" $6 "\\\" \""}'
```

Which produces output lines like this for each application

> "curl -s http://webapp.apps.example.com/cloudfoundryapplication/health
>   | jq \".status\" && echo \"webapp.example.com\" "

I can run that line one at a time by doing this:

```
bash -c "curl -s http://webapp.apps.example.com/cloudfoundryapplication/health | jq \".status\" && echo \"webapp.example.com\" "
```

Next I want to pipe all the commands into parallel and run them all at once:

```
cf apps | tail -n +5 | awk 'NF{print "\"curl -s http://" $6 "/cloudfoundryapplication/health | jq \\\".status\\\" && echo \\\"" $6 "\\\" \""}' | parallel
```

But that's where I get stuck I get this for each of the lines:

> /usr/bin/bash: curl -s
>   http://webapp.apps.example.com/cloudfoundryapplication/health | jq
>   ".status" && echo "webapp.apps.example.com" : No such file or
>   directory

Searching around online some people are having similar problems with shell expansion, but I don't see where that would be going on with my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is my extra double qoutes around the whole command.

Here is the final working command:

```
cf apps | tail -n +5 | awk 'NF{print "curl -s http://" $6 "/cloudfoundryapplication/health | jq \".status\" && echo \"" $6 "\" "}' | parallel
```